# Drinking a Dua?

Tags: dua, islamic-basis

When my Auntie was pregnant she would put a paper in some water and drink it. I am not sure what it was and why she would do it. The paper had some writings and she would want to wash the writing off the paper and drink it. I think it had verses of the Qur'an or some kind of Du'a because it was Arabic writing.

And i also heard her telling my mum she never used to believe in these things until she tried it and she felt as though she would have died before drinking the water.

I want to know if anyone knows what this paper was and what it was for? And is this actually allowed in Islam?

Answer (score 2):

That thing is known as Taweez.

Wikipedia article: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta'wiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27wiz)

Well they actually really are Quranic verses, but they are used in a very bad manner, do you believe that drinking the verses of Quran would make you a mother of a son? I don't think a Muslim would believe in that. He would infact recite the Holy verses many times a day, rather than drinking them all.

It doesn't work! Taweezat are a work of street side uneducated people who, just for earning their own life, make fool of the people with some money! No offence, I don't mean to mention your aunt here, but yes, people who have lost their faith in Allah do such things.

Instead of going to a street side Baba for a Taweez, people can offer their prayers 5 times a day, to get their wishes fulfilled instead of drinking those Quranic verses.

I want to answer your question with a question.

> Would ink, when drunk, purify your soul or would it go to your stomach and make you sick?

Islam teaches us to pray to Allah, to get help in our daily life. But these taweez would make us go to Baba to get the help. Is that allowed in Islam? No it's not, you need to ask Allah for help, rather than using these methods. They are haram, and are considered as Shirk, for you believe that someone other than Allah can help you survive or pass the hard time!

Comment: Isn't taweez something like a thread or amulet you tie on your hand , leg or neck?

Answer (score 2):

## Research

I was quite surprised the moment I read the question. I never thought any would be doing it. Nevertheless, I couldn't help but to research for what it could be.

In Islamweb, there is a fatwa about it citing many resources that supports the practice as long as what is written is not undecipherable.

Maliki school of Fiqh says it is not allowed, while others (e.g. Shafi'i) is in position it being permissible. ([Source](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=7852))

Another source says that it is in a disagreement position between scholars if the Dua was from Quran, otherwise it is considered bid'a (innovation in religion, which implies being Haram). ([Source](http://www.drhatemalhaj.com/qa/index.php/2011/03/18/they-write-something-on-paper-put-the-paper-into-water-then-drink-it/)) It also mentions that it was not practiced by prophet Muhammad PBUH.

## Personal Opinion

Given the above mentioned research, I still in a position of objecting the use of such things. I can not agree with such things because they are more like superstitious doings. Allah is nearer to us than we think, and by doing so, drinking Dua, is like we think that Allah, exalted Him, needs a way to help us.

Allay says:

> And We have already created man and know what his soul whispers to him, and We are closer to him than [his] jugular vein (Quran 50:16)

For thus, I totally object these doings.